# how can i get correct this undefined index error

Tags: php

how do i get ride of this error? i know most of the time when something like this pops up,i can use the `isset function` but what i tried is not working ,how can i correct this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: real in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\captcha2\index.php on line 12
```

my code on line 12 is this below

```
$real = $_session['real'];
```

this is my php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
session_start();
$_session[] = "";
$real = $_session['real'];
$guess = $_POST['captcha'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($real == $guess){

echo "hi $name,you types the correct name";
} 
else {

    echo "Nooo";
}

} else {
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Do you know what the error message means?  Have you looked at any of the **dozens** of dupes in the Related sidebar?

Comment: best way for you to start is http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['real'])) {
    $real = $_SESSION['real'];
}
```

This checks to see if the session is set before it assigns the value

Comment: im getting undefined variable real when i use this code and when i say 4real = ""; my code is running but its only printing the no statement

Comment: define `$real` above the statement then. `$real = ""` then the if statement

Comment: im trying to create a captcha when i enter the correct values its supposed to print you have enter the correct value but instead its saying no,is the real variable causing this?

Answer (score 6):

I pressume you want to use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_session`, they are not the same thing.